# Creating an instance of Abstract Class in a different class

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, nullreferenceexception

Im trying to create an instance of an abstract class (Employee)

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }

    public static SchoolEmployeesContext ctx = new SchoolEmployeesContext();

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCommencement { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Department DepartmentOfEmployee { get; set; }

}
```

Now im trying to fetch an Employee from a context, for multiple functionalities, such as editing and removing an employee. Declaring that the Employee is null in the Method has allowed to remove the *"Unassigned"* error. But whilst running this is obviously giving me a *"null reference exception"*

Method to Find Employee Below:

```
 public Employee Search(int EmpId)
        {
            var Emp = from emp in ctx.Employees
                      where emp.EmployeeId == EmpId
                      select emp;

            Employee Found = null;

            foreach (Employee e in Emp)
            {
               Found.EmployeeName =  e.EmployeeName;
               Found.EmployeeSurname = e.EmployeeSurname;
               Found.Address = e.Address;
               Found.Grade = e.Grade;
               Found.Salary = e.Salary;
               Found.DateOfCommencement = e.DateOfCommencement;
               Found.Username = e.Username;
               Found.Password = e.Password;
               Found.DepartmentOfEmployee = e.DepartmentOfEmployee;
            }


            return Found;
        }
```

Comment: In order to answer this more fully, could you explain why you need the Employee class to be abstract?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're looping through the results and assign their property values to a non-existinent value. In each loop iteration (if it would work), you are overwriting the values again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.
They can be inherited from, and the inherited type can be instantiated, but not instantiated directly.

Looking at your code, this is (I think) what you want to do:

Remove `abstract` from your class definition

Also, you have a completely unused static within your `Employee` class -

```
public static SchoolEmployeesContext ctx = new SchoolEmployeesContext();
```

So I'd suggest removing that.

Your `Employee` class then becomes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCommencement { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Department DepartmentOfEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your `Search` method looks a little suspect.

You're selecting *many* Employees from the database, where `EmployeeId` is equal to the supplied `EmpId`
Doesn't look right to me.

You can use LINQs `SingleOrDefault` to retrieve the single item by ID (or null, if it doesn't exist)

So your `Search` method would now look like

```
public Employee Search(int EmpId)
{
  //this will return the single employee
  var Emp = ctx.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.EmployeeId == EmpId);

  return Emp;
}
```

Comment: Maybe also recommend that the line `public static SchoolEmployeesContext ctx = new SchoolEmployeesContext();` should be removed entirely.

Comment: @Alex Thank you !! Very Helpful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate abstract classes. Here you can find more information about them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf(v=vs.71).aspx

> Abstract classes are closely related to interfaces. They are classes that cannot be instantiated, and are frequently either partially implemented, or not at all implemented.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot create an instance of an abstract class because it does not have a complete implementation. The purpose of an abstract class is to function as a base for subclasses. It acts like a template, or an empty or partially empty structure, you should extend it and build on it before you can use

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes can not be instantiated. In the code you have supplied there is no need for Employee to be abstract, so you should remove the abstract modifier from your Employee class definition.

As others have pointed out, your Search method seems wrong and should be changed to select the employee entity that matches the employee id and, if found, mapping that entity to an Employee. Something like this:

```
public Employee Search(int EmpId)
{
    // Return the employee with the correct Id (or null if not found).
    var employeeEntity = ctx.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.EmployeeId == EmpId);
    return employeeEntity == null
        ? null
        : new Employee
          {
              EmployeeName = employeeEntity.EmployeeName,
              EmployeeSurname = employeeEntity.EmployeeSurname,
              ...
          };
    }
}
```

should give you a working solution.

Comment: At the time of writing, the accepted answer returns an Employee entity from the DataContext rather than an Employee object, which I believe is incorrect given the original question. I add this as a comment here because, also at the time of writing, I have insufficient reputation to comment on anything other than my own posts.